# Is a moving wind turbine more efficient?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, efficient-energy-use

To begin with, let’s get the elephant out of the room; No, I’m not asking about free energy.

Now onto the question:
Wind turbines have a peak efficiency at some wind speed. Say the wind speed is bellow this peak and the wind turbine is on a moving vehicle, used to propell the vehicle forward. Will the turbine become more efficient as the vehicle picks up speed and the wind speed relative to the vehicle equals the speed which gives the maximum efficiency for the turbine?

Comment: Are you asking if *just* the turbine is more efficient? Or if the car-turbine system is more efficient? Your sentence structure is weird: Is the turbine supposed to be powering the car? (this last one does make it perilously close to a free energy question)

Comment: I’m mostly asking about the efficiency of the turbine itself, though since it is powering the ”car” it should also be directly related to the efficiency of the car-turbine system. I know that it feels a lot like ”free energy”, took me quite a while to figure out why it isn’t and the maximum speed you can drive a wind powered car given a certain wind speed. But I am not trying to extract more power than I put in, I’m simply using the turbine as an advanced sail so I can travel directly against the wind.